# I need to ask the user to reenter password before a certain workflow. How do I achieve that using AzureB2C?

Tags: angular, azure-ad-b2c

One of the problems we are trying to solve is to have the user reenter their password before navigating to a specific page. We use AzureB2C for authentication and an Angular front end. I want know how I can achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Honestly , nothing concrete, was hoping if there is an explicit means to do it.

Comment: One of the things that we were thinking about to use the Azure Graph Api to get the token again and validate with the current user info. I am not completely sure if its secure enough.

Comment: Hi @sandeepkumarmahendran! Probably it is a configuration on the AzureB2C resource. Look at this [Set up self-service password reset for your customers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-sspr). It may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using msal library in Angular, you can have your msal service invoking for credential again by

```
this.msalService.loginPopup().then((token) => {
  // you will have valid token and all your businesss logic here
  console.log('Popup successful', token);
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.log('Popup failed', err);
});
```

You may have to valid user with previous session and new session.